# Visual Studio Multi Device Hybrid App how to add uses-permission to AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, visual-studio-2013, android-manifest, visual-studio-cordova

I'm trying to add a user-permission to the AndroidManifest.xml file, however I think this file is generated as part of the build process. So where would I add this and to which file.

This is what I need to add to get added to the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the uses-permission feature within a Cordova application, you will need to use a custom plugin that can handle this code.

For example, the [Phonegap NFC plugin](https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc) should be easy enough to use.

To include the plugin in your Multi-device Hybrid Apps project, open your config.xml file and then add an entry:

```
<vs:feature>link_to_github_repo_here</vs:feature>
```

OR

Create a folder called "plugins" in your project root and paste the downloaded plugin into the folder.

Comment: How does this answer the question? What does a NFC plugin do to fix the `uses-permission` problem?